# How to develop D-pad navigation on React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, d-pad

I am using React Native to develop app for ODG R-7 smart glasses that run on Android 4.4 KitKat. I'd like to develop D-pad navigation as specified in https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html.

I believe the key would be to correctly set the nextFocusDown, nextFocusUp, nextFocusLeft, nextFocusRight properties of the underlying native Java components. I just don't know how.

Has anyone made this work and how?